# Change apache port number on virtual host configuration file

Tags: apache2

I am trying to change the port number on which apache runs on Ubuntu 20.04.I have configured docker to run on port 80.So I am trying to make apache run on port 8081.I have followed this tuitorial https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-change-port-number-in-apache-in-ubuntu/ and managed to change the port on the Apache server configuration file.But when I try to change it on the virtual host configuration file with `sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`I cant since the file is not editable. When I open it via GUI I can edit the port but I can not save the changes. Been stuck on this for a while. I will appreciate any help

Comment: How is the file not editable? When you change the port and save, does the new value not persist? Did you remember to restart Apache after updating the configuration file? 

Answer (score 0):

This is because /etc/apache2/sites-available/ files are only editable by sudoer users (regarding security issues which may happen). From the terminal, you can run *sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf* and you will be able to save the file with ctrl + s.

On the other hand, it is not quite recommended to edit the same 000-default.conf file and keep it as the one running for apache, as it can be used later as a template for other virtual hosts. So what I recommend you is copying this file to a file called domain.conf (replacing domain for your actual domain) with *sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.conf* and configuring this .conf vhost instead of the default one.

Also remember to enable the site once created with the command *sudo a2ensite domain.conf*. It is also important to execute this command being on the path in which de .conf is, so first run cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and then enable the site with *sudo a2ensite domain.conf*.

Comment: @Diego Manzanares thanks. That worked for me